# error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer

Tags: c

```
int get_first(int arr[],int count)
{

   int half = count / 2;

   int *firstHalf = malloc(half * sizeof(int));
   memcpy(firstHalf, arr, half * sizeof(int));
   return firstHalf;
}

int get_second(int arr[], int count)
{
    int half = count / 2;

    int *secondHalf = malloc(half * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(secondHalf, arr + half , half * sizeof(int));
    return secondHalf;
}

int result = get_first(arr, count);
int size = sizeof(result) / sizeof(result[0]);
```

i am writing a function that split an array into two equal parts. the function takes in an array and the size of the array. I am testing the function by storing the first half of the array in the result and print its length. But when I build the function, the line

```
int size = sizeof(result) / sizeof(result[0]);
```

gives an error says "error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer"

Is it because my function failed to pass the first half of the array into result? or the way of storing an array is wrong? If so, how do I split the array, can someone help me to fix it? thanks in advance.

Comment: `int result` means that `result` is a scalar, so you can't do `result[0]`, which assumes `result` to be an array or a pointer.

Comment: Your functions probably need to return a pointer (`int *get_first(…)`, `int *get_second(…)`), but there are problems with how the calling code knows the size of the half that it gets back.  You're likely to need to rethink this quite a lot.

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler Right now I am just struggling with split the array into two parts, does it looks like my function is correct?  I also tried to print the value of result[0] but it still failed.

Comment: @  500 - Internal Server Error So how do I get the value in the result? I tried to print result[0] but it failed.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you write something like 42[0], zhangdi?

Comment: @zhangdi, you say that you are trying to split the array into two. You already know the value for count. When you split the original array to half, the sizes of the halves will be count/2 anyway.

Comment: Fair warning, even when this is fixed I suspect you'll be sad when an odd-count element array (say, 11) ends up with first and second "halves" that do not accumulate to the original total (in this case, two 5-element halves due to integer division rules). Might want to prepare for that reality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems that I can see:

1. In functions `int get_first(int arr[],int count)` and `int get_second(int arr[], int count)` you are returning int pointers but functions' return type are int.
2. result is declared as int but you are accessing it like result[0].

Correction for 1 is obvious from point 1 above.
Correction for 2:

Instead of:

```
int result = get_first(arr, count);
```

You should write:

```
int *result = get_first(arr, count);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This explains part of the problem, but I think it's important to know that `sizeof(result) / sizeof(result[0])` will not calculate the size of a dynamically allocated block of memory.

Comment: Problem with this advice is that it results in code that won't complete.  `get_first()` returns an `int`.   So `int *result = get_first(arr, count)` attempts to assign an `int` value to a pointer.   That is invalid.

Comment: He already mentioned that in point 1.  Although, it would've been better if he just mentioned what to do to fix it.